# How can I replace all white pixels of the widget to black pixels in flutter?

Tags: flutter, pdf, mobile, drawing, pixel

I have a syncfusion pdf library to render pdf files and I need to implement a global dark mode that applies to pdf files too. I came up with the idea to replace white pixels to black and black pixels to white. How can I do this?

I tried using `CustomRepaint` like so:

```dart
class WhiteToBlackPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  Future<void> paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) async {
    // Create a paint object with black color.
    final paint = Paint()..color = Colors.black;

    // Draw the widget's background with black color.
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height), paint);

    // Get the pixel data of the widget using its `toImage()` method.
    ui.Image image = await (ui.window.render(ui.window.physicalSize)).toImage();
    ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData();
    Uint8List pixelData = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();

    // Loop through each pixel in the pixel data, and if the pixel is white, change its color to black.
    for (int i = 0; i < pixelData.length; i += 4) {
      if (pixelData[i] == 255 &&
          pixelData[i + 1] == 255 &&
          pixelData[i + 2] == 255) {
        pixelData[i] = 0;
        pixelData[i + 1] = 0;
        pixelData[i + 2] = 0;
      }
    }

    // Create a new image from the modified pixel data.
    ui.Image newImage = await ui.decodeImageFromPixels(
      pixelData.buffer.asUint8List(),
      image.width,
      image.height,
      ui.PixelFormat.rgba8888,
    );

    // Draw the modified image on the widget's canvas.
    canvas.drawImage(newImage, Offset.zero, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

it did not even drew a widget

after this, I tried using `ColorFiltered`:

```dart
ColorFiltered(
  colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
    Colors.white,
    BlendMode.difference),
  child: pdf
)
```

but it replaces all pixels even if they are not white or black.

Comment: Potentially the widgets are not rendered on screen yet when WhiteToBlackPainter.paint() is called by flutter?

Comment: @jraufeisen I can't even get widget image to redraw it, so its not the issue